# Using state in method - React

Tags: reactjs

I've got a method called **devCreateSteps** and I want to use state in that but it throws an error saying;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTemplateUsed' of undefined

Here's the snippet of my code;

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      tableLoading: false,
      modalHeader: "",
      isTemplateUsed: false
    };
  }

  devCreateSteps = [{
    title: 'Info',
    content: (<StepOne isTemplateUsed={this.state.isTemplateUsed} />),
  }, {
    title: 'Device',
    content: (<StepTwo />),
  }, {
    title: 'Location',
    content: (<StepThree />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Properties',
    content: (<StepFour />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Controls',
    content: (<StepFive />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Summary',
    content: (<StepFinal />),
  }];
```

The problem is I can't use

> isTemplateUsed={this.state.isTemplateUsed}

this in the **devCreateSteps**

What is the right way to use state to send it as props ?

Comment: do you have react console. If yes please tell me what do you have in `state `for `StepOne` component

Comment: It actually throws the error before going to StepOne component. I have a console to see the state in StepOne but it never goes to there.

Comment: But this is my state in StepOne; 

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isTemplateUsed: this.props.isTemplateUsed
        };
    }

Comment: this will work if `state` is a class prop also, not done in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `devCreateSteps` as a class property directly in class, do it in the `componentWillMount` function.

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      tableLoading: false,
      modalHeader: "",
      isTemplateUsed: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.devCreateSteps = [{
    title: 'Info',
    content: (<StepOne isTemplateUsed={this.state.isTemplateUsed} />),
  }, {
    title: 'Device',
    content: (<StepTwo />),
  }, {
    title: 'Location',
    content: (<StepThree />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Properties',
    content: (<StepFour />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Controls',
    content: (<StepFive />),
  },
  {
    title: 'Summary',
    content: (<StepFinal />),
  }];
  }

}
```

Also define state as a property intializer too.

```
class App extends React.Component {


    state = {
          modalVisible: false,
          tableLoading: false,
          modalHeader: "",
          isTemplateUsed: false
        };

    devCreateSteps = [{
        title: 'Info',
        content: (<StepOne isTemplateUsed={this.state.isTemplateUsed} />),
      }, {
        title: 'Device',
        content: (<StepTwo />),
      }, {
        title: 'Location',
        content: (<StepThree />),
      },
      {
        title: 'Properties',
        content: (<StepFour />),
      },
      {
        title: 'Controls',
        content: (<StepFive />),
      },
      {
        title: 'Summary',
        content: (<StepFinal />),
      }];


    }
```

> **P.S.** make sure you have `stage-2` added as a `preset to babel` in you
>   `webpack` config, since `property initializers` are not part of ES6.

Comment: what is difference between these two ? can you please explain bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTemplateUsed' of undefined

Because you are using state variable named `open` before initializing , you can avoid this error by two ways either

- try to initialize variable with empty array and then assign values using state wihtin constructor.

  ```
   devCreateSteps: [];

  constructor(props, state) {
  super(props, state);
  this.state = {
    open: this.props.open
  }
  console.log(this.props, this.state);
  this.devCreateSteps = [{
    title: 'Info',
    content: (<p isTemplateUsed={this.state.open} />)
  }]
  }
  ```
- or you can use `componentWillMount` as suggested in above answer.